# error in returning duplicates after loop through results

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code currently

```
def buildPointsTable(teams, results):   
teams=['Colombia', 'Japan', 'Mexico', 'France']
results=['Mexico, France, 4, 6', 'Japan, Mexico, 8, 2', 'Colombia, Mexico, 3, 9', 'Colombia, Japan, 9, 7', 'Colombia, France, 2, 8', 'Japan, France, 4, 4']
points=[]
score=0


for t in results:
    t=t.split(', ')
    if t[2]>t[3]:
        score=score+3

        if t[0] not in points:
            points.append([t[0], score])

        else:
            points.append(score)



    elif t[2]<t[3]:
        score=score+3

        if t[1] not in points:
            points.append([t[1], score])

        else:
            points.append(score)



    elif t[2]==t[3]:
        score=score+1

        if t[0] not in points:
            points.append([t[0], score])

        elif t[1] not in points:
            points.append([t[1], score])

        else:
            points.append(score)



    score=0
return points
```

This is what I am returning

```
[['France', 3], ['Japan', 3], ['Mexico', 3], ['Colombia', 3], ['France', 3], ['Japan', 1]]
```

I need 'teams' that win (if they score higher 3 is added, if they tie 1 is added) twice or win and tie to not return separately. As above I returned ['France', 3] twice because they won twice. 
Results is in the format [t1,t2,s1,s2] where s1 is score of t1 and s2 is score of t2

Comment: Why are you using a list for the results? The elements are not equivalent. It would be better to use dicts with the scores, e.g. {'Mexico':4,'France':5}

Comment: for my assignment, the results are given in a list. When they test my code, they will insert the list of results into the function...

Comment: What is your question, again?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
scores = dict.fromkeys(teams,0)
```

and when incrementing scores:

```
scores[t[0]]+=3
```

or

```
scores[t[1]]+=3
```

etc.

This will make a dictionary with the teams as keys and give every team a score of 0. Then it will do a lookup on the winning team name and increment the value of its score.